# CodeMirror does not work with React/Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, codemirror

I'm working on some markdown editor for my react project.
I wanna use CodeMirror as the code editor, but it seems it does not working when I build it with webpack.

If be honest, CodeMirror are in the DOM-tree, textArea is hidden, but everything I see is:

[image]

and

[image]

UPD: The same code works perfect on codepen. I guess it's a problem with webpack.

some code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {Editor} from './components';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<Editor />, rootElement);
```

components/editor.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import cm from 'codemirror';
require('codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown');

export class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.codeMirror = cm.fromTextArea(this.refs.editor, {mode: 'markdown'})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea ref='editor' autoComplete='off' defaultValue='default value' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config.dev');

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 3000;

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/app/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
});
```

and webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Please check out [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) for usage with React

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [webpack gitter chat](https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack) [@bebraw](https://github.com/bebraw) answered to my question:

> Codemirror works with webpack but it takes some extra setup. you need
>   to bring some css etc. for it to render. [example](https://github.com/survivejs/react-demos/blob/master/demos/index.js)

Comment: Terry___S I wish you had posted an actual answer because I still can't find the solution and I have the exact same issue as you...

Comment: Yes, it's an actual answer. You should just import some codemirror's css in your entrypoint file as it did in the example `import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'; import 'codemirror/theme/monokai.css';`. You also should use `style-loader` to load this css.

Comment: I have the same issue if the hot reload (HMR) is enabled. The only way was to disable the hot reload. Still don't know why.

Comment: here is an example of using codemirror + webpack: https://github.com/webpack/playground, also take a look at the react-toolbox docs folder: https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/dev/docs/app/components/editor/index.jsx